# How can I write a query where my order by clause varies?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a query that looks like:

```
object CategorySort extends Enumeration {
    type CategorySort = Value
    val ID, Price, CostPrice = Value
}

object SortDirection extends Enumeration {
    type SortDirection = Value
    val Asc, Desc = Value
}

def getProducts(categoryId: Int, sort: CategorySort, sortDirection: SortDirection): List[Product] = {
  val q = for {
    p <- products if p.categoryid === categoryId
  } yield p
  p.sortBy(o => o.id.desc).list()
}
```

The above function doesn't currently use my sort and sortDirection parameters.

Is there a way for me to modify my function so it can handle all the sort cases in an elegant manner?

The only way I know how currently is to use a switch statement but it will get very complicated because of the sort direction.

I am sure there is a smarter way to do this.

Comment: I would just use plain SQL query...

Comment: @Ashalynd then I will loose typesafety.

Comment: I also tried to have something like this, instead of using `enumeration`s I tried to pass a `ColumnOrdered[T]` without success, in the end I got the feeling that it wasn't possible, hope somebody will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That thing bugged me too. I ended up implementing this trait, which I implement in my table classes. In your sortBy you can then call o.colByName(...) and sort according to the direction.

```
trait Sortable {
  protected val orderColMap: Map[String, Column[_]]
  def colByName(colName: String) = orderColMap.get(colName)
}
```

still not very elegant, because it forces you to implement a map for each table, but at least saves you the switch/match.